# JavaScript(regex): excluding matches from output

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this text: **nisi non text600 elit** where **600** is added dynamically. How can I get it?

```
var str = ('nisi non text600 elit').match(/text\d+/);
alert(str);
```

This alerts **text600**, how can I alert only **600** without an additional replace of the word **text**(if that is possible)?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var str = ('nisi non text600 elit').match(/text(\d+)/);
alert(str[1]);
```

Comment: Gives an error message, as `str` is null. You have to remove the apostrophes around the regular expression literal.

Answer (score 5):

Use parentheses to catch a group in the regular expression:

```
var str = ('nisi non text600 elit').match(/text(\d+)/)[1];
```

Note: A regular expression literal is not a string, so you shouldn't have apostrophes around it.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExDwU/). You need to capture something in the regular expression, which is done using the `(` and `)`.

The result will be an array there index `0` is the whole match applied on the string and the following indicies are your captures.

Comment: Index 0 in the array contains the whole match, not the whole input string.

Answer (score -1):

```
alert(str.substr(14, 16) )
```

Try this

Comment: While that will work in this case, it's entirely reliant on the specific sequence being in exactly the same place in the string every time. Which makes it rather fragile for real-world use in variable-content strings. Also, not my down-vote.

Comment: The number is dynamic, so it's not always 3 digits.